# Activate JTextArea on program launch?

Tags: java, swing, click, jtextarea

Is it possible to make a `JTextArea` in a way that when the user starts to type when the program is launched it's it automatically starts to type in that JTextArea. Normally the the user first has to click on the JTextArea to start to type in it?

Can I make it that the user does not have to click a JTextArea to start typing it?

EDIT: I've tried using:

```
textField.requestFocusInWindow();
```

inside my frame class but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This called to *gain focus* and is configurable with your code. There are some [samples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JTabbedPane/Gain_focus_on_JTextArea_when_selecting_a_new_JTabbedPane.htm) which use Listeners to change `JTextArea` at the proper time.

Method `.requestFocusInWindow();` might fix your problem in the code bellow:

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(e -> {
  Component comp = tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
  if (comp.equals(pnlFoo)) {
    txtFoo.requestFocusInWindow();
  } else if (comp.equals(pnlBar)) {
    txtBar.requestFocusInWindow();
  }
});
```

Similar issue : [Java - how do I gain focus on JTextArea when selecting a new JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265326/java-how-do-i-gain-focus-on-jtextarea-when-selecting-a-new-jtabbedpane)

This could help for your first run :

```
frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                        textArea_1.requestFocusInWindow();
```